# Error calling SPCommands when running multiple MYSQL Stored Procedures

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php but not as a programmer...

I am having difficulty calling and displaying the content when I call a procedure more than once in a page.  I am trying to display two separate record sets from two different SP calls for MYSQL.  I can display the first call but the second fails.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but perhaps someone can kind help?

I keep getting the error when I call the second procedure:

Error calling SPCommands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I'm running on windows btw

Code below... PHP

```
// First call to SP
$page = 2;
$section = 1;

include("DatabaseConnection.php"); //general connection - works fine

$sql = 'CALL GetPageContent("'.$page.'", "'.$section.'")';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error calling SP' .mysqli_error($conn));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   // DO STUFF< REMOVED TO MAKE READING CLEARER
}

mysqli_free_result($result);

//SECOND CALL BELOW


$section = 2; // change parameter for different results

$sql = 'CALL GetPageContent("'.$page.'", "'.$section.'")';

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die('Error calling SP' .mysqli_error($conn));


while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   // DO STUFF< REMOVED TO MAKE READING CLEARER
}


mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Comment: Could you please not ask your question in the title of the question? Or at least start by dropping the shouting of: PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is that your SP is giving you multiple results.

Use the mysqli_multi_query, see https://www.php.net/mysqli_multi_query

Comment: Hi,

Thank you, I saw this link earlier but could not figure it out.

Would you be able to re-write what I am doing?  I tried that multi method 2 or 3 times but just got worse errors.

I just need one working example and I through the problem... I would really appreciate it...

Let me know if that is cool or not.

Thank you either way.

Lewis

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I saw this link earlier but could not figure it out. Would you be able to re-write what I am doing? I tried that multi method 2 or 3 times but just got worse errors. I just need one working example and I through the problem... I would really appreciate it... Let me know if that is cool or not. Thank you either way. Lewis –